# Adding values in a column in a table either in the table or on a report

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that has two columns that record number values. These columns are number fields.
I can't figure a way to add these fields up so that I have a total.

```
DriverName             Positive Points   Negative Points   
John Doe                      5
Jane Doe                                         1
John Doe                                         3
Jane Doe                      25
John Doe                      10                 5
Jane Doe                                         10
John Doe                      5
Jane Doe                                         1
```

What I need is a way to record in a table and display on a form

```
John Doe                     20                  8
Jane Doe                     25                 12
```

Than I going to need to take these numbers and subtract/Add them from 100
John Doe                     100+12 = 112
Jane Doe                     100+13 = 113

So than if John and Jane are on the same team the team total would be 125

Which than I want to display on a form and on a report.

I am lost on how to do this in access but could do it in excel but excel won't had the other data I must record involving team members and teams.

Any help will be great and this is not a school assignment but a real world application for the business I work at.

Thanks

Comment: is the entire table of data always on the same team or is there another table that shows the teams?

Answer (score 0):

As with so many things in Excel, there are numerous ways to accomplish that and "which one you should use" could depends on many different things.

Given what I understand of your example, I would use a simple Pivot Table.

[image: pivot tables]

Pivot Tables are a powerful tool capable of in depth data analysis.  This is the most simple way to use them.  If you're unfamiliar with them, be sure to read some of the documentation [like these](https://www.google.ca/search?q=pivot%20tables%20site:microsoft.com).

Comment: Great reply and that's how I would do it in excel also. My problem is that I have to do this in Access because of the other information I must record about the teams also.